# When GraphViewChange.elementsToRemove is launched

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor, behavior-tree

I select the necessary nodes, press delete and nothing happens GraphViewChange.elementsToRemove remains empty. At the same time, if I want to move some node, then GraphViewChange.moveDelta works as it should, I checked it, just to make sure that I didn't mess up with subscribing to the graphViewChanged event
why aren't elements being added to GraphViewChange.elementsToRemove. GraphViewChange is parameter of the method that I subscribe to the graphViewChanged event